# Perform MySQL select on unsorted digits

Tags: mysql

I am working on an application that requires me to validate if 3 randomly generated numbers match a 3 digit string that has been entered into a database from user input.  I also need to preserve the exact order that the user enters the string, so sorting on input is not an option.

For example, the randomly generated digits may be 6 4 0, and in the database a string may show as '406'.

Is there an easy way this can be accomplished in a single query without enumerating the options or adding an extra column/view?

Comment: By _match a 3 digit string_, do you actually mean that to just verify that each of the 3 digits appears in the database string? Are there always exactly 3 digits? Can they be repeated in the database like `665`?

Comment: Yes, I am looking to verify if the string in the database contains all three digits.  It will always be exactly 3 digits, and numbers can be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you could try

```
create table y (z varchar(10));
insert into y values ('406');
insert into y values ('604');
insert into y values ('446');
insert into y values ('106');
insert into y values ('123');
```

and then

```
SELECT * from y where FIND_IN_SET(Substring('640',1,1),MAKE_SET(7,Substring(z,1,1),Substring(z,2,1),Substring(z,3,1))) and FIND_IN_SET(Substring('640',2,1),MAKE_SET(7,Substring(z,1,1),Substring(z,2,1),Substring(z,3,1))) and FIND_IN_SET(Substring('640',3,1),MAKE_SET(7,Substring(z,1,1),Substring(z,2,1),Substring(z,3,1)));
```

returns

```
406 
604
```

Comment: Thanks! it look like this should work.  I have run a few other test cases, and this is returning the expected hits. Now, need to sit down and make sure I completely understand this ;)

Comment: this only works because it's mysql :-) I've never saw such strange built-in functions in a database like that before. everyday we learn something new ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sum the three random digits

Something like

```
Select * From Triplets Where (Ascii(Substring(Number,0,1)) - 48) + (Ascii(substring(Number,1,1)) -48) +
(Ascii(substring(Number,2,1)) -48) = MySumOfNumber
```

easy is a state of mind isn't it, Storage requirement of an extra "CheckSum" int, versus the high cost of a query like this.

Comment: 1+3+9 = 13,
2+4+7 = 13,
?

Comment: @Leo. oops, good point. Probably an idea not worth salvaging, even though it would narrow down the options to test for.